# Mastercard currency conversion rates

Tags: foreign-exchange, mastercard

I was looking at a [product disclosure statement](http://www.cashpassport.com/1/Global/Australia/1/TD483%20CPP%20Chip+PIN%20AU%20Generic%20PDS%20low%20res.pdf), and the card charges a margin for foreign transactions above the exchange rate set by Mastercard. Does Mastercard have its own spread and how could I find out about how much this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rates charged by Mastercard would be the standard card [also called card rate / sheet rate] rates for the day. This would be similar to the rates displayed by Bank's. However the standard rates vary a bit from one institution to other. This is normally not called spread. However since Mastercard is doing Fx, there are enough margins. Typically Mastercard would aggregate all small transactions and get a better rate from market.

Comment: Mastercard and Visa also used to charge 3% over and above the small-customer rate (as opposed to the better rate that they actually got by aggregating the many daily small transactions into one big overall exchange of currency).  They were sued over it and the class-action suit was settled fairly recently.  I got back about $60 as a settlement.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Do you know under what grounds they were sued?